# How can I modify the maximum value of my progress bar

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

So, I'm making a progress bar that is getting its values from some variables I have declared, all is working well except there is one issue. When my aria-value now meets my aria-value max there is still space left over in the progress bar since it fills the width of it to only 80% and not 100%. So I'm kind of stuck on a fix for this. Here's my Code

```
 <?php 
      $current_players=$infosprp['players'];
      $max_players=$infosprp['places'];
      $width = $current_players;

      echo '<div class="progress w-25 m-auto" style="height: 30px;">
      <div class="font-weight-bold progress-bar bg-warning progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated text-center" 
           role="progressbar" 
           aria-valuenow="'.$current_players.'"
           aria-valuemin="0" 
           aria-valuemax="'.$max_players.'"style="width:'.$width.'%;font-size:18px;">
           '.$width.'/'.$max_players.'
      </div>
    </div>'; 
?>
```

[Here is a picture of the result when the progress bar is filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMWBh.png)

I'm bad at explaining things, so I hope you were able to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of process bar is 100%. In your image displaying 80% completed, so you use
new varibale like   `$statusBar = ($current_players * 100) / $max_players;`

Please see below example, I think it's should work for you.

```
 <?php 
          $current_players=$infosprp['players'];
          $max_players=$infosprp['places'];
          $width = $current_players;
          $statusBar = ($current_players * 100) / $max_players;

          echo '<div class="progress w-25 m-auto" style="height: 30px;">
          <div class="font-weight-bold progress-bar bg-warning progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated text-center" 
               role="progressbar" 
               aria-valuenow="'.$current_players.'"
               aria-valuemin="0" 
               aria-valuemax="'.$max_players.'"style="width:'.$statusBar.'%;font-size:18px;">
               '.$width.'/'.$max_players.'
          </div>
        </div>'; 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The width should be the percentage of `$current_players` divided by the `$max_players`. It is only filling up to 80% because the `$width` is only 80 (players) as shown in the image you linked. The computation for `$width` should be the following:

```
$width = $current_players / $max_players * 100;
```